# How can I get two separate animations to play upon a single onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Let me start off by saying I am new to CSS/HTML coding in general. Mostly learned by breaking down others codes and rebuilding them. So, I am by no means a professional and maybe in well over my head for this. My terminology may be off as well. Sorry in advance.

What I would like to do is open two separate animations upon clicking one button, is that possible? I have a feeling I will need to learn Javascript to do this but I wasn't too sure if there was a way to do it strictly via CSS.

So the "Where are you?" and the 'BEHIND' animation wouldn't play until the button is clicked instead of the "Where are you?" just playing upon load.

```css
#Screen {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #909090;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/dotnoise-light-grey.png');
  border: 2px solid #111;
  z-index: 2
}

#Button1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 175px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 110px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 15px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/600x315/ef/a4/54/efa454458c927ff79e21b898bbd446f0.jpg');
  background-color: #101010;
  z-index: 3;
}

.tab div {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: px;
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab div:target {
  display: block;
}


/*Flicker-in-1 is for the screen to "flicker on"*/

.flicker-in-1 div {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: px;
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: flicker-in-1 2s linear 1s both;
  animation: flicker-in-1 2s linear 1s both;
}


/*Minified this block of code*/

@-webkit-keyframes flicker-in-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.2% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20.6% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30.6% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  57% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  57.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  65.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  77.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  86% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  86.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.text-focus-in {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 600px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #909090;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/dotnoise-light-grey.png');
  border: 2px solid #111;
  z-index: 2 -webkit-animation: text-focus-in 2s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
  animation: text-focus-in 2s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes text-focus-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes text-focus-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Orbitron";
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Screen"></div>

<div class="text-focus-in">Where are you? </div>

<a href="#Behind">
  <div id="Button1"></div>
</a>
<div class="flicker-in-1 tab">
  <div id="Behind">
    <h1>BEHIND</h1>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey bud, so what you're looking for is to trigger an animation after the "Where are you?" animation is done playing, correct?

Comment: Kind of? I know that I need to use delays to get the animations to play out as I need them to. What I want is the "Where are you" to not play/pop-up until the same button that triggers the "Behind" is pressed.

Comment: Okay, so you could technically use the CSS animation route, just know that you're writing way more code than needed. If you want to really learn how to code I'd recommend atleast digging into vanilla JS. Every developer on here started where you are. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/mrosata/gb96gcme/2

Comment: As far as an answer goes, I would say the easiest way to do it would be to use the same container, then hide the "Where are you?" text, then have the BEHIND YOU! text pop-in after the "Where are you?" fades. That would solve your triggering issues and prevent you from writing a ton more keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little trick. It relies on a checkbox next to the animatable thing and tracking its state ( using a selector like `#toggle:checked ~ #animatable_element`). You can toggle it clicking the label.

```css
#animatable_element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

#toggle {
  display: none; /* optional */
}
#toggle:checked ~ #animatable_element {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {background-color: orange;}
  50% {background-color: yellow;}
  100% {background-color: orange}
}

#animatable_element_2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#toggle:checked ~ #animatable_element_2 {
  animation-name: example_2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example_2 {
  0% {background-color: blue;}
  50% {background-color: purple;}
  100% {background-color: blue}
}
```

```html
<label for='toggle'>Click me to start or stop the animation</label>
<input id='toggle' type='checkbox'/>
<div id='animatable_element_2'></div>
<div id='animatable_element'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.animation-box {
background-color:gray;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="animation-box">
    <span class="fade-in-and-fade-out-animation">"Where are you?"</span>
    <h1 class="pop-up-blinking-animation">RIGHT BEHIND YOU!!</h1>
</div>
<button class="btn">Start Animation</button>
```

**Solution** Trigger animation using the button element and layer the animations on the same container, or you may need to dig into JavaScript, specifically into [JS queues](https://jsfiddle.net/mrosata/gb96gcme/2).

Answer (score 0):

This works by using javascript: `element.classList.add("flicker-in-1");`
Adding the class's when button is clicked.

```js
function here() {
  var element = document.getElementById("here");
  var element2 = document.getElementById("Behind");
  element.classList.add("flicker-in-1");
  element.classList.add("tab");
  element2.classList.remove("hide");
}
```

```css
    #Screen {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #909090;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/dotnoise-light-grey.png');
  border: 2px solid #111;
  z-index: 2
}

#Button1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 175px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 110px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 15px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/600x315/ef/a4/54/efa454458c927ff79e21b898bbd446f0.jpg');
  background-color: #101010;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab div {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: px;
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Flicker-in-1 is for the screen to "flicker on"*/

.flicker-in-1 div {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: flicker-in-1 0s linear 0s both;
  animation: flicker-in-1 0.5s linear 0s both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}


/*Minified this block of code*/

@-webkit-keyframes flicker-in-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.2% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20.6% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30.6% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  57% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  57.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  65.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  77.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85.1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  86% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  86.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.text-focus-in {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 600px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  Height: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #909090;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/dotnoise-light-grey.png');
  border: 2px solid #111;
  z-index: 2 -webkit-animation: text-focus-in 2s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
  animation: text-focus-in 2s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes text-focus-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes text-focus-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Orbitron";
  text-align: center;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="Screen"></div>

<div class="text-focus-in">Where are you? </div>

<button id="Button1" onclick="here();"></button>
<div id="here">
  <div class="hide" id="Behind">
    <h1>BEHIND</h1>

  </div>
</div>
```

PS: You have to Expand snippet to see it correctly.

Comment: Alright so, when I run this snippet it still plays the "text-focus-in" upon loading vs onclick along with the "flicker-in". HOWEVER, this does help me look at javascript and not be so scared of learning it. Thank you for your help!!